# Remove item from SharedPreference list [android]

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I want remove checked elements from my list, but not only from main app but from SharedPreferences also. Now, in my app i can remove chcecked elements but not from SharedPreferences, so if i come back to my activity all of removed elements are still visible. Please, help me.

This is my activity:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter;
    List<String> localization;
    Button btnDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_moje_miejsca);

        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("coordinates", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Set<String> localizationSet = preferences.getStringSet("localization_set", new HashSet<String>());
        localization = new ArrayList<>(localizationSet);

        for (String listPosition : localizationSet) {
            list.add(listPosition);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        setListAdapter(adapter);


public void onClickBtnDelete(View view){

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
    int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

    for(int i = itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){

        if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
            int position = i + 1;
            adapter.remove(list.get(i));    

        }
    }

    editor.remove("localization_set").commit();
    itemCount = getListView().getCount();

    checkedItemPositions.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    for (int i = itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){

        localization.add((String) list.get(i));
        setLocalization = new HashSet<String>(localization);
        editor.putStringSet("localization_set", setLocalization).commit();

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. It's my mistake. I forgot clear a list and thats why the list duplicate itself. It's enough to add a localization.clear() method to solve this problem

Answer (score 16):

To remove a specific saved pref then use

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove("tag_to_delete");
editor.commit();
```

To remove all of your saved preferences then use this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: But i want remove only few elements from list and editor.remove() remove whole list. For example, i have MyList in my preferences and it is: 1. cat, 2. dog, 3.lion, 4 crown.  I want remove from my list only lion and dog.

Comment: So first remove the items from the list with list.remove(position) and save it again.

Comment: Look at my edit post if You can ( into onClickDeleteBtn method ). Now i removed selected items from activity and remove whole list from SharedPreferences and then I saved there a new list without removed elements. But still when i'm running onCreate method i get old list from SharedPreferences.

Comment: The addition of setLocalization to your prefs should occur outside of you loop and try using apply() instead of commit()

Comment: I found a problem. It's my mistake. I forgot clear a list and thats why the list duplicate itself.
It's enough to add a localization.clear() method to solve this problem.